# Algorithm for converting Serial Date (Excel) to Year-Month-Day in C++

Tags: c++, date, datetime, parsing, c++17

This [post here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2750/Excel-Serial-Date-to-Day-Month-Year-and-Vice-Versa) provides a very neat & pure C++ algorithm for converting a serial date (Excel) to its explicit year-month-day representation (and back). Let me paste a compressed version for convenience:

```cpp
void ExcelSerialDateToDMY(int nSerialDate, int& nDay, int& nMonth, int& nYear)
{
    // Modified Julian to DMY calculation with an addition of 2415019
    int l  = nSerialDate + 68569 + 2415019;
    int n  = int(( 4 * l ) / 146097);
    l      = l - int(( 146097 * n + 3 ) / 4);
    int i  = int(( 4000 * ( l + 1 ) ) / 1461001);
    l      = l - int(( 1461 * i ) / 4) + 31;
    int j  = int(( 80 * l ) / 2447);
    nDay   = l - int(( 2447 * j ) / 80);
    l      = int(j / 11);
    nMonth = j + 2 - ( 12 * l );
    nYear  = 100 * ( n - 49 ) + i + l;
}

int DMYToExcelSerialDate(int nDay, int nMonth, int nYear)
{
    // DMY to Modified Julian calculated with an extra subtraction of 2415019.
    return int(( 1461 * ( nYear + 4800 + int(( nMonth - 14 ) / 12) ) ) / 4) +
           int(( 367 * ( nMonth - 2 - 12 * ( ( nMonth - 14 ) / 12 ) ) ) / 12) -
           int(( 3 * ( int(( nYear + 4900 + int(( nMonth - 14 ) / 12) ) / 100) ) ) / 4) +
           nDay - 2415019 - 32075;
}
```

For example

```
 2019-06-22 <--> 43638
 2000-01-28 <--> 36553
 1989-09-21 <--> 32772
```

---

The above post is from 2002, so I am wondering whether there are alternative implementations, which are better. By "better" I mean e.g. faster, shorter or less obscure. Or even algorithms, which perhaps provide a certain amount of pre-calculations (e.g. record 1 Jan serial date for a desired range of years, say 1900 to 2200, and then perform a fast look up).

Comment: *By "better" I mean e.g. faster, shorter or less obscure* -- What is slow about the code you've posted?  It is using integer and some basic math operations.  Lightning fast.  And yes, you can easily store these in a hash table once computed, all better known in computer science as [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  But is it worth it, given that the calculation itself maybe faster than the lookup (if you store things in a hash table)?  As far as obscure, that's the nature of these type of date calculations.  They are not meant to be "easy on the eyes".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithms you show are very good.  On my platform (clang++ -O3) they produce object code with no branches (pipeline stallers) and no accesses to far away memory (cache misses).  As a pair, there is a range of validity from -4800-03-01 to millions of years in the future (plenty of range).  Throughout this range they model the Gregorian calendar.

[Here are some alternative algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) that are very similar.  One difference is that yours have an epoch of 1900-01-01 and the ones I'm presenting have an epoch of 1970-01-01.  However it is very easy to adjust the epoch by the difference of these epochs (25569 days) as shown below:

```
constexpr
std::tuple<int, unsigned, unsigned>
civil_from_days(int z) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits >= 18,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit unsigned integer");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<int>::digits >= 20,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit signed integer");
    z += 719468 - 25569;
    const int era = (z >= 0 ? z : z - 146096) / 146097;
    const unsigned doe = static_cast<unsigned>(z - era * 146097);          // [0, 146096]
    const unsigned yoe = (doe - doe/1460 + doe/36524 - doe/146096) / 365;  // [0, 399]
    const int y = static_cast<int>(yoe) + era * 400;
    const unsigned doy = doe - (365*yoe + yoe/4 - yoe/100);                // [0, 365]
    const unsigned mp = (5*doy + 2)/153;                                   // [0, 11]
    const unsigned d = doy - (153*mp+2)/5 + 1;                             // [1, 31]
    const unsigned m = mp + (mp < 10 ? 3 : -9);                            // [1, 12]
    return std::tuple<int, unsigned, unsigned>(y + (m <= 2), m, d);
}

constexpr
int
days_from_civil(int y, unsigned m, unsigned d) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits >= 18,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit unsigned integer");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<int>::digits >= 20,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit signed integer");
    y -= m <= 2;
    const int era = (y >= 0 ? y : y-399) / 400;
    const unsigned yoe = static_cast<unsigned>(y - era * 400);      // [0, 399]
    const unsigned doy = (153*(m + (m > 2 ? -3 : 9)) + 2)/5 + d-1;  // [0, 365]
    const unsigned doe = yoe * 365 + yoe/4 - yoe/100 + doy;         // [0, 146096]
    return era * 146097 + static_cast<int>(doe) - (719468 - 25569);
}
```

These algorithms are valid for millions of years both forward and backwards (including prior to -4800-03-01).  Though that extra range won't buy you much because the Gregorian calendar didn't even start until 1582-10-15.

I compiled both pairs of algorithms on macOS using `clang++ -O3 -S` and the set I have produces slightly smaller object code (about 10%).  Though they are all so small, branch-less and cache-miss-free, trying to verify that benefit by measuring performance would be a challenging exercise.

I do not find the readability of either set superior to the other.  However this pair of algorithms does come with an [irritatingly exhaustive derivation](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) for those who are curious how these algorithms work, and unit tests to ensure the algorithms are working over a range of +/-1 million years.

One could gain a very slight bit of performance in the above algorithms by limiting the range of validity to [2000-03-01, 2400-02-29] by setting `const int era = 5` in both algorithms.  I have not performance tested this option.  I would expect such a gain to be in the noise level.

Or there might be some miniscule performance advantage by limiting the range from [0000-03-01, millions of years forward] by not accounting for negative values of `era`:

In `civil_from_days`:

```
const int era = z / 146097;
```

In `days_from_civil`:

```
const int era = y / 400;
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you! Appreciate the mention of the "irritatingly exhaustive derivation" post.